# Trazer apenas o nome na ListView, mas relacionar com o ID

Tags: java, android, listview

Tenho um WebService que lista todos os meus usuários e traz os usuários do banco.

Tenho uma classe

```
Usuario {
int id;
String nome;
}
```

Com seus construtores, gets e sets, etc.

E consigo retornar todos os meus usuários.

Porém, quero jogar tudo isso em uma ListView. Consegui. Mas consegui usando um ArrayAdapter de Strings e uma lista de String, ou seja, passo apenas o nome.

Como vou conseguir associar esse nome ao seu id do banco pra poder recuperar mudar de tela usando o evento OnItemClickListener(), se eu passo apenas o nome?

Tem como fazer isso sem precisar exibir o id na tela? (sem usar duas textviews, etc).

Quero usar uma ListView mesmo, apenas mostrar o nome. Mas tenho que filtrar na outra tela pelo id usando o putextra, etc.

A minha dificuldade é associar o ID ao Nome, já tentei criando uma lista de Users, mas não fica do jeito que quero.

E agora, o que faço?

Comment: quando inflamos um Adapter nossa lista é enumerada com uma `position`, quando o metodo `OnItemClickListener()` for chamado, ele saberá qual posição da lista foi selecionada, no momento não consigo colocar um exemplo, mas assim que possivel eu posto aqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você pretende apenas que a lista apresente o `nome` uma forma simples é fazer o *Override* do método `toString()` da sua classe *Usuario*:

```
public class Usuario {
    int id;
    String nome;
    .....
    .....
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

<sub>***Nota:*** O *ArrayAdapter* usa o método `toString()` do objecto que ele contém para obter o valor a apresentar na lista.</sub>

Depois é usar normalmente, só que em vez de `ArrayList<String>` é `ArrayList<Usuario>`:

```
ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

ArrayAdapter<Usuario> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<Usuario>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, usuarios);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

No `onItemClick()` você pode obter o `id` do item clicado da seguinte forma:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        Usuario usuario = (Usuario)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        String id = usuario.getId();
    }
});
```

***Note bem:*** Apesar de neste caso funcionar a forma correcta seria implementar um *custom adapter*.

Comment: Desculpa pela demora. Mas funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado! Paz e luz!