# Dado enviado de uma activity para outra chega nulo

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Minha Activity que estou exibindo os dados do banco no listview

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_visualizar_clientes);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);


    GenericDAO g = new GenericDAO(getApplicationContext());
    ArrayList<Cliente> cArray = g.getClientes();

    final List<String> itens = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < cArray.size() ; i++) {
        Cliente c = new Cliente();
        c = cArray.get(i);
        itens.add(c.getNome());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itens);
    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    //inserindo evento de click no listView e enviando os dados para a segunda activity

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                                int posicao, long id) {

            long cli = adapter.getItemIdAtPosition(posicao);
            Intent it = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Tela_Emprestimo.class);
            it.putExtra("idCliente", cli);

            startActivityForResult(it, 1);
        }
    });
```

minha segunda activity aonde estou recebendo os dados, só que não estou recebendo o nome do cliente

```
public class Tela_Emprestimo extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable{
    Cliente cliente;
    TextView txtCliente;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela__emprestimo);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        cliente = (Cliente)i.getSerializableExtra("idCliente");
        Toast.makeText(this, "cliente :" + cliente.getNome(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    }
}
```

A classe Cliente

public class Cliente implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String rua;
    private String bairro;
    private String numero;
    private int idcidade;
    private int idFuncionario;

```
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getRua() {
    return rua;
}

public void setRua(String rua) {
    this.rua = rua;
}

public String getBairro() {
    return bairro;
}

public void setBairro(String bairro) {
    this.bairro = bairro;
}

public String getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(String numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public int getIdcidade() {
    return idcidade;
}

public void setIdcidade(int idcidade) {
    this.idcidade = idcidade;
}

public int getIdFuncionario() {
    return idFuncionario;
}

public void setIdFuncionario(int idFuncionario) {
    this.idFuncionario = idFuncionario;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O que você está a incluir no Extra é um `long`, suponho que o Id do cliente, e não o Cliente(objecto).
Ao tentar fazer, na Activity Tela_Emprestimo, o *cast* para Cliente

```
cliente = (Cliente)i.getSerializableExtra("idCliente");
```

o resultado é `null`;

Veja como está a fazer:

```
long cli = adapter.getItemIdAtPosition(posicao);
Intent it = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Tela_Emprestimo.class);
it.putExtra("idCliente", cli);
```

Se quer passar um Cliente, terá de ter um método no Adapter que retorne um, qualquer coisa como `Cliente getItemAtPosition(posicao){...}`.

O código ficaria assim:

```
Cliente cli = adapter.getItemAtPosition(posicao);
Intent it = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Tela_Emprestimo.class);
it.putExtra("idCliente", cli);
```

Para que tudo funcione como foi dito, necessita de usar um *custom adapter* que possa lidar com objectos do tipo Cliente.

Como alternativa, já que a lista apenas usa o nome de cliente, use um `ArrayList<Cliente>`, faça o *override* do método `toString()` da classe Cliente e obtenha o Cliente do item clicado no método `onClick()` da seguinte forma: `Cliente cli = (Cliente)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);`.
Veja um exemplo nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70674/2541).

<sub>A classe Cliente deverá implementar a interface `Serializable`, seria preferível que ela [implementasse `Parcelable`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38471/2541).</sub>

Comment: modifiquei a classe cliente para parcelable e adicionei os methodos nela, só que está dando erro em - Cliente cli = adapter.getItemAtPosition(posicao);

Comment: Esse método tem de ser escrito por você. Julgo que, para evitar que surjam novos problemas, seria melhor primeiro fazer funcionar com Serializable antes de alterar para Parcelable.

Comment: Mais mesma usando serializable, fica aparecendo o erro em Cliente cli = adapter.getItemPosition(posicao); fala que cli tem que ser do tipo long

Comment: Você tem de criar, caso não exista, um método no Adapter que retorne o Cliente correspondente à `posicao`. O nome que eu usei na resposta(`getItemAtPosition()`) foi apenas um exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Como vc esta usando esta forma para adicionar os dados a intent, se usar o nome do cliente ficará mais fácil de recuperar

```
String cli = adapter.getItemIdAtPosition(posicao);//Pega o nome do cliente da lista, pois vc populou a lista com um List de nomes dos clientes
Intent it = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Tela_Emprestimo.class);
it.putExtra("idCliente", cli);//Adiciona o nome do cliente a Intent
```

A variavel `cli` é um String do nome do cliente, na activity seguinte vc deve procurar por um String, assim:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String clienteName = i.getStringExtra("idCliente"); //Aqui vc tem o nome do cliente
```

E então basta instanciar sua classe de pesquisa no banco e criar um metodo para pegar o cliente a partir do nome que vc recebeu na activity

```
GenericDAO g = new GenericDAO(this);//usar this se estiver em uma activity
Cliente cli = g.getClienteByNome(clienteName);
```

Comment: o problema e por que não está passando o nome do cliente para segunda activity, quando eu coloco para exibir pelo Toast.makeText() aparece que está null

Comment: Vc esta numa falha grotesta de logica, e vc esta usando esse ArrayAdapter que é bem genérico, e quando vc chama o Adapter de novo vc esta chamando o ArrayAdapter de nomes que vc criou anteriormente, agora se vc fizer o seguinte, criar uma variavel com a lista de nomes na activity, depois do click da lista vc pegar a posição e buscar na lista, vc vai ter o objeto inteiro do cliente